# Python 2.5.6 vs 2.4.3

Tags: python, python-2.5, python-2.4

I created a python script with Python 2.5.6 (Windows), tested it and it worked correctly. After I put it on the Server (python 2.4.3, Linux) it compiled, but didn't work. It didn't gave me any traceback or whatsoever. Since it is a trac system it called the Script but then Timed out.

I narrowed the cause down to a few functions, which only appear in the new file:

```
cursor.fetchall()
```

or

```
for x in y
   if(x == 1):
      break #does this work?
```

or

```
FILE operations
```

Is there a common thing I have overseen or does somebody know what it could be?

Due to restrictions I am not able to use python 2.4 as dev. I need to work with Trac Standalone which only works with python 2.5.x.

Comment: In what sense did it "not work"? Did you get an error -- if so, could you post the traceback? Did nothing happen?

Comment: BTW Python 2.4 is now hideously out of date and you should try to get the server updated.

Comment: Sadly there was absolutely no traceback given, and yes, it is out of date. But the server doesn't belong to me and I can't update it...

Comment: This should be a SyntaxError in any version of Python: `if (x = 1):`.

Comment: Well according to this -> http://pypi.python.org/pypi/adodbapi/2.4.0.1 document maybe 2.4 returns something else then a list when calling fetchall()?

"The result of fetchall() and fetchmany() will be an object which emulates a sequence of sequences."

Answer (score 3):

See [What's new in Python 2.5](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html) for the definitive list of features that have been added in Python 2.5. It's pretty extensive. In particular:

> New modules include ... the SQLite database module (`sqlite`)

Generally, the 2.x series of releases maintain *backwards* compatibility. However, you seem to be expecting *forward* compatibility, which is a different thing.

My advice is twofold:

1. Python 2.4 is very old. If you can, get the server upgraded to a more recent version of Python.
2. Regardless of the outcome of the #1, get the dev box onto the same version of Python that you're going to use in production. It would also help if the dev box used the same OS as the prod box (in a virtual machine, if need be).